# Redirection input in C: fgets() end of line "\n" interfering with strcmp()

Tags: c, string, fgets, strtok

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int individualAverage(int data[][20],int j)
{
    int k,average=0;
    for(k=0;k<10;k++)
    {
        average += data[k][j];
    }
    return average;
}

int main()
{
    int var,indAvg=0;
    int i=0,j,k;
    char *experiments[20];
    int data[10][20];
    char str[100],str2[100];
    char *ptr, *token;
    int no_line=1;


    while(fgets(str,100,stdin) != NULL && (strcmp(str,"*** END ***") && strcmp(str,"*** END ***\n")))
    {
        if(no_line % 2 == 0)
        {
            k=0;
            token = strtok (str," ");
            while (token != NULL)
            {
                sscanf (token, "%d", &var);
                data[k++][i] = var;
                token = strtok (NULL," ");
            }
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr = strdup(str);
            experiments[i] = ptr;
        }
        no_line++;
    }

    fgets(str,100,stdin);
    token = strtok(str," ");
    while(token != NULL && (strcmp(token,"4") && strcmp(token,"4")))
    {
        sscanf (token, "%d", &var);
        printf("DATA SET ANALYSIS\n1.\tShow all the data\n2.\tCalculate the average for an experiment\n3.\tCalculate the average across all experiments\n4.\tQuit\nSelection: %d\n\n",var);
        switch(var)
        {
        case 1 :
            for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                printf("%s",experiments[j]);
                for(k=0;k<10;k++)
                {
                    printf("%d ",data[k][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
            break;
        case 2 :
            printf("What experiment would you like to use?\n");
            token = strtok (NULL," ");
            sscanf (token, "%s", &str);
            for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                if(strcmp(experiments[j],str) == 0)
                {
                    indAvg = individualAverage(data,j); 
                    printf("Experiment: %s",experiments[j]);
                    printf("The individual average of the experiment is %d\n",indAvg);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
    }
}
```

OK, so I have a method that takes lines of redirection input. The lines come in pairs. First line is the name of an experiment, and the second line has the 10 values separated by spaces for that experiment. After these pairs, there is an ending line `"*** END ***"`

After this line, there is one last line holding the instructions of what to do with the data.

I'm currently having a problem where I've used `fgets()` to store the strings of the first pairs of lines into a variable which I declared as `char *experiments[20];`

Each of strings that this array is pointing to will have `'\n'` at the end of the string because of `fgets()`

Back to the last line of instructions. You have values 1-4. Right now I'm looking at instruction 2. It tells the average of an experiment. So after 2 on the last line, there must be the name of one of the experiments. I've used:

```
char str[100];
int var;
char *token;
token = strtok(str, " ");
sscanf (token, "%d", &var);
```

to get the first value on the line into `var` (pretend it's 2). So after that would be a string. Say it's `Test 1`, I'll use

```
token = strtok (NULL," ");
sscanf (token, "%s", &str);
```

to get the value into `str`, and then I'll compare it to `experiments` for all possible indexes.
HOWEVER, because `fgets()` gives `'\n'` at the end of the lines, all of the experiments strings will have `'\n'` at the end while `str` will just have the name of the experiment WITHOUT `'\n'` therefore they will never be equal even if `'\n'` is the only difference between the strings.

Any solutions?

Comment: Could you provide your working code-in-question and mark the place where you're experiencing problems with a comment? You are saying that you use `fgets()` but I don't see `fgets()` being used anywhere...

Comment: I've updated it with my code. As you can see experiments is basically fed the line right from `str` which comes from `fgets();`

Comment: Why don't you like the removal of `'\n'` solution?

Comment: I don't dislike it, it's just that I read this in the man-page of getline and thought it would be simpler: Extracts characters from `is` and stores them into `str` until the delimitation character delim is found **(or the newline character, '\n', for (2)).**

Comment: According to [this page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), `getline` does include the `\n`, and `getdelim` will include the delimiter character that you specify... Not that I personally know about those functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you know that there may be a `\n` at the end of the string, you could check for it, and remove it if it's there:

```
size_t len = strlen(str);
if (len != 0 && str[len-1] == '\n') {
    str[len-1] = '\0';
}
```

This would terminate the line at `\n`, so your `strcmp` would succeed. An alternative is to use `strncmp`, and pass the length of the target string. This runs the risk of false positives when there's a longer suffix that `\n`, though.

You could also read your data like this:

```
fscanf(f, "%99[^\n]", str);
```

Comment: is there a function better than fgets() that won't keep `\n`?

Comment: I've just found getline() and I'm thinking that could make everything easier?

Comment: @user32542 Yes, it would. You could also use fscanf(f, "%99[^\n]", tmp) to read your strings. 99 is the length of your buffer minus one for null terminator.

Comment: I'm not really understanding this. What is tokens exactly? I don't see how tokens is an array

Comment: I'm not opening a file in my program, I'm redirecting it in the command line as such: program < info.txt

Comment: nevermind. your first solution now makes sense. YOU ARE A LIVESAFER

Comment: `getline` is not part of the ISO C standard and is typically associated to DOS/Windows (I think) and involves console i/o. `fgets` is an ISO C core function and involves streams; it is probably preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own version of `fgets` that doesn't store the new-line character when it encounters one, and call it `myfgets`. Something like this would replicate `fgets`'s behaviour, I think, produced with respect to the [description given in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37dh6kf.aspx):

```
char * myfgets( char * str, int n, FILE * stream ) {
    if ( n <= 0 ) return NULL;  // won't accept less than or equal to zero length

    int currentPos = 0;
    while ( n-- > 0 ) {
        int currentChar = fgetc( stream );
        if ( currentChar == EOF ) return NULL;
        if ( currentChar == '\n' ) break;
                    // if these two lines were in reversed order, 
                    // it would behave same as the original fgets
        str[currentPos++] = currentChar;
    }
    return str;
}
```

But of course the other solution is simpler, hehe...